# Does $G$ is nilpotent imply so is $G/Z(G)$?

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is nilpotent then is $G/Z(G)$ also nilpotent? If so, how can I prove it?

I know the definition of nilpotent group that the *upper central series* of $G$ goes to $G$ in the finite length.

Comment: See Prop. 51 of [this](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jbritnel/Teaching/GTnotes5.pdf).

Comment: @Analysis It is bad form to edit your question, especially as there was an answer already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the question has completely changed, so now I have to completely change my answer.

Given any normal subgroup $N\triangleleft G$ and subgroup $H\le G/N$, it corresponds to a subgroup of $G$, namely the preimage of $H$ under the projection map $G\to G/N$. This is the union of all of the cosets of $N$ that are present in $H$. Call this the pullback.

If $Z_i(G)$ is the $i$th center of $G$, then the $i+1$th center $Z_{i+1}(G)$ is as the pullback to $G$ of the center $Z(G/Z_i(G))$.

It should be intuitively clear that $Z_i(G/Z(G))=Z_{i+1}(G)/Z(G)$; try to verify it.