# If $G$ is nilpotent then so is $G/Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

**The Problem**: If $G$ is nilpotent then so is $G/Z(G)$.

**My Background**: Chapter 1-5 of *Abstract Algebra $\mathit{3^{rd}}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote.

> For any group $G$ define the following subgroups inductively:
>
> $Z_0(G)=1, Z_1(G)=Z(G)$, and $Z_{i+1}(G)$ is the subgroup of $G$
> containing $Z_i(G)$ such that $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G)=Z(G/Z_i(G))$ (i.e.,
> $Z_{i+1}(G)$ is the complete preimage in $G$ of the center of
> $G/Z_i(G)$ under the natural projection). The chain of subgroups
> $$Z_0(G)\leq Z_1(G)\leq\dots$$ is called the *upper central series* of
> $G$. A group is called *nilpotent* if $Z_c(G)=G$ for some
> $c\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**My Attempt**: Taking hint from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/893671/506332), I tried to show that $Z_i(\overline{G})=Z_{i+1}(G)/Z(G)$, where $\overline{G}=G/Z(G)$. We proceed by induction on $i$.

**Base Case**: $i=1$, then $Z_1(\overline{G})=Z(\overline{G})=Z(G/Z(G))=Z_2(G)/Z_1(G)=Z_2(G)/Z(G)$.

**Induction Hypothesis**: Suppose $Z_{i-1}(\overline{G})=Z_i(G)/Z(G)$.

Now, we have
$$
Z_i(\overline{G})/Z_{i-1}(\overline{G})=Z(\overline{G}/Z_{i-1}(\overline{G}))=Z(G/Z(G)/[Z_i(G)/Z(G)]),\tag1
$$
where the first equality is by the definition of the upper central series of $\overline{G}$ and the last equality is by the induction hypothesis. By the *Third Isomorphism Theorem*, $G/Z(G)/[Z_i(G)/Z(G)]\cong G/Z_i(G)$, hence $Z(G/Z(G)/[Z_i(G)/Z(G)])\cong Z(G/Z_i(G))$, thus $(1)$ becomes
$$
Z_i(\overline{G})/Z_{i-1}(\overline{G})\cong Z(G/Z_i(G))=Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G),\tag2
$$
where the last equality is by the definition of the upper central series of $G$. **Screeching halt**.

I realize that the isomorphism I derived did not really help. But thinking of $Z_i(\overline{G})$ as the complete preimage in $\overline{G}$ of the center of $\overline{G}/Z_{i-1}(\overline{G})$ did not quite offer any insight on its relation with $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z(G)$ either, which is supposed to be an equality. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ClydeKertzer I appreciated the help but that link you provided is literally in the first sentence of my proof...

Comment: Actually any homomorphic image (or factor group)  or subgroup of a nilpotent group is nilpotent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $G$ is nilpotent imply so is $G/Z(G)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893666/does-g-is-nilpotent-imply-so-is-g-zg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember exactly what the isomorphism is.

The isomorphism
$$\frac{G/N}{M/N} \cong \frac{G}{M}$$
is induced by the map $G/N \to G/M$ given by $xN \longmapsto gM$.

If we let $\overline{G}=G/Z(G)$, and we assume we already know that $Z_{k}(\overline{G}) = Z_{k+1}(G)/Z(G)$, then to prove that $Z_{k+1}(\overline{G}) = Z_{k+2}(G)/Z(G)$ we need to show that $Z_{k+2}(G)/Z(G)$ are precisely the elements of $\overline{G}$ that map to the center of
$$\frac{\overline{G}}{Z_k(\overline{G})} = \frac{G/Z(G)}{Z_{k+1}(G)/Z(G)}.$$

Let $g\in G$. Then:
$$\begin{align*}
gZ(G)\in Z_{k+2}(G)/Z(G) &\iff g\in Z_{k+2}(G)\\
&\iff gZ_{k+1}(G)\in Z(G/Z_{k+1}(G))\\
&\stackrel{*}{\iff} (gZ(G))\left(\frac{Z_{k+1}(G)}{Z(G)}\right) \in Z\left(\frac{G/Z(G)}{Z_{k+1}(G)/Z(G)}\right) \\
&\iff \left(gZ(G)\right)Z_{k}(\overline{G})\in Z\left(\frac{\overline{G}}{Z_k(\overline{G})}\right)\\
&\iff gZ(G)\in Z_{k+1}(\overline{G}).
\end{align*}$$
Thus, $Z_{k+2}(G)/Z(G) = Z_{k+1}(\overline{G})$.

The step tagged with a $*$ above the biconditional is the one that you are having trouble with. This comes because the isomorphism between $G/Z_{k+1}(G)$ and $\frac{G/Z(G)}{Z_{k+1}(G)/Z(G)}$ is induced as noted above: starting in $G/Z(G)$, you map $xZ(G)$ to $xZ_{k+1}(G)$. That means the induced isomorphism is
$$(xZ(G))\left(\frac{Z_{k+1}(G)}{Z(G)}\right) \longmapsto xZ_{k+1}(G).$$
In particular, $x\left(\frac{Z_{k+1}(G)}{Z(G)}\right)$ lies in the center  of the corresponding group if and only if $xZ_{k+1}(G)$ lies in the center of $G/Z_{k+1}(G)$. That gives the equivalence in question, with $x=gZ(G)$.

Comment: @DickGrayson: No, that's not a typo; I'm taking $x$ to be an arbitrary element of the group in question, and I purposefully did not denote it as a coset.

Comment: I read "...if and only if $\mathbf{x}Z_{k+1}(G)$ lies in the center of $G/Z_{k+1}(G)$" and I assumed that the two $x$'s are the same...

Comment: @DickGrayson: It would be "$(xZ(G))Z_{k+1}(G)$", since it would have to be an element of the corresponding quotient.