# Conjecture: if $H$ is characteristic in $G$ and $K\leq G$ such that $K\cong H$, then $H=K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group, characteristic-subgroups

**The Conjecture**: If $H$ is characteristic in $G$ and $K\leq G$ such that $K\cong H$, then $H=K$.

We know that $\sigma(H)=H$ for all $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(G)$. Hence the a more general question here is: does every isomorphism $\tau: H\to K$ between two subgroups $H$ and $K$ extend to an automorphism of $G$? If yes, then the conjecture will hold immediately.

Any confirmation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is false. In the Heisenberg group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$, the center is characteristic, but there are plenty of other groups of order $p$ different from the center.

Comment: It is very rare to be able to extend an isomorphism $\tau\colon H\to K$ between two subgroups of $G$ into an automorphism of $G$. There is a whole machinery for building overgroups of $G$ where we can guarantee this happens (and in fact where we can find a group $\mathfrak{G}$ containing $G$ as a subgroup, and an element $t\in\mathfrak{G}$ such that conjugation by $t$ restricted to $H$ yields $\tau$). It's called HNN extensions.

Comment: For another explicit example, in the dihedral group of order $8$, $D_8=\langle r,s\mid r^4=s^2=1, sr=r^3s\rangle$, the center $Z(D_8)=\{1,r^2\}$ is characteristic, cyclic of order $2$, and there are four other subgroups isomorphic to the center: $\{1,s\}$, $\{1,rs\}$, $\{1,r^2s\}$, $\{1,r^3s\}$.

Comment: Another counterexample: $\mathbb{Z}$. Its non-trivial subgroups are $\mathbb{Z}, 2\mathbb{Z}, 3\mathbb{Z}, 4\mathbb{Z}, \ldots\;$, which are all isomorphic to each other. As $\mathbb{Z}$ has only two automorphisms, the identity and the inversion $x \mapsto -x$, it's easy to verify each of these subgroups is characteristic.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you so much my friend! This question came up when I was trying to prove that $G$ is nilpotent $\implies G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent. I'd really appreciate it if you could take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4594053/506332).  Regardless: thanks again!